# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql-server

When I run my SQL query I get subquery errors:

```
SELECT 
    [FileName], [FilePath] 
FROM 
    dbo.[tb_CrawlData] cr  
WHERE 
    cr.Content LIKE '%' + (SELECT content 
                           FROM [tb_CrawlData]
                           WHERE Content like '%test%') + '%'  
GROUP BY 
    cr.FileName, [FilePath] 
ORDER BY 
    cr.FileName
```

Below screenshot is my database:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exists` instead:

```
SELECT [FileName], [FilePath]
FROM dbo.[tb_CrawlData] cr  
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM [tb_CrawlData] cd
              WHERE cd.Content like '%test%' AND
                    cr.Content like '%' + cd.Context + '%'
             )
GROUP BY cr.FileName, [FilePath] 
ORDER BY cr.FileName ;
```

Comment: @Gordon...Wow! that was quick and great answer.
Thanks for the help <3.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your query:

```
SELECT [FileName],[FilePath] FROM dbo.[tb_CrawlData] cr  
WHERE cr.Content like '%' + (SELECT content FROM [tb_CrawlData]
WHERE Content like '%test%') + '%'  GROUP BY cr.FileName,[FilePath] 
ORDER BY cr.FileName
```

How is that not the same as this?

```
select distinct FileName, FilePath
from tb_CrawlData
where content like '%test%'
order by FileName
```

Comment: @Dan...yes the output same. Thanks for the help.
How to put that statement into my c#?